# Spring Batch - Best Way to implement process

Tags: spring-batch

I want to know which is the better way to implement process in spring batch... I read a lot but spring  batch offer differents way to implements a process.

1. I have to retrive list from a mysql database
2. For each row of the step 1, i have to retrive another list from another mysql.
3. iterate the list of list to create an excel file
4. update the list of list in the mysql to mark that are processed
5. for the first list, i have to notify the user sending a mail.

EDIT:

Put what im thinking to solve this problem, and if you want, use it to guide me

Create 2 steps:

First Step

1. Create reader to get the first query
2. Create a processor to add the second query on each item on the first
3. Create a writer for create excel and put all the records on jobContext to pass to the next step

Second Step (Tasklet)

4. Get records from the job context, update and send email for each one

Comment: What are the solutions you designed to solve your problem? If you share them, we can help you to choose the "best" one.

Comment: i edit my post with my solution

Comment: Yes, your solution is a good option IMO. In Step 2, will the second list contain the same type of items? Is it a different table in the same mysql instance or is it a different db server? I'm asking to see if it is possible to combine step1 and step2 with a `join` query.

Comment: no, the types for the two lists is same like Clientes and Orders per clients

Comment: ok I see, this basically the [driving query pattern](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#drivingQueryBasedItemReaders). One thing you need to pay attention to is: `put all the records on jobContext to pass to the next step`: try to not put a lot of data in the execution context as this is persisted between steps. A list of item IDs is ok, but a full list of all items is not a good idea.

Comment: Another thing to be careful about is that the driving query pattern may not perform well for large data sets (known as the n+1 problem due to the additional query for each item). HTH, good luck!

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thanks a lot for your point. How can i solve if i have a large data set ? and i have to do something with whole data ?

Comment: For large data sets, you can try partitioning and use the same pattern for each partition. The advantage is that all partitions will be executed in parallel.

Comment: Could you giveme an example how to ? think i hace to sync the process to summarize the data